# Change the IP address of OpenShift Origin VM

Tags: openshift-origin

I am trying to run OpenShift Origin VM (Vagrant+VirtualBox) but I need to assign another IP.
I have tried to use in Vagrant file:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

When testing it is fully ignoring it. The console says:

```
https://10.2.2.2:8443/console
```

When accessing

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443/console
```

I see OpenShift and "Loading..." but then it redirects to

```
https://10.2.2.2:8443/oauth/authorize?client_id=openshift-web-console&response_type=token&state=%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F10.2.2.2%3A8443%2Fconsole%2Foauth
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i'm wondering how to do the same.  Did you ever figure this out?  I found this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060422/how-to-re-route-the-openshift-private-address-to-a-public-one/41065268#41065268, but changing all of the occurences in the the master-config.yaml wasn't enough, the service then fails to start, and I'm not sure how to regenerate all of the certs

Comment: Unfortunately I did not solve it and used  the normal install on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this issue and this is what worked for me:

1. Create a new *Host Only* network adapter via VirtualBox menu `[File] -> [Settings] -> [Network]`
2. Assign this network the IP address `10.2.2.2`
3. Stop the OpenShift Origin VM and add the just created network to the machine
4. Start the VM, https://10.2.2.2:8443 should be reachable now